# How to make a logo where a letter is made of particles of varying sizes?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo

How can I make a logo in Adobe Illustrator like the AntiParticle logo below, from http://www.graphicdesigninspiration.net/2012/08/15/70-awesome-logo-designs-for-your-inspiration/?

It is a large number circles of different, varying sizes, which form the shape of a text character.

[image: http://www.graphicdesigninspiration.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/AntiParticle.png]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

My example is not a perfect, but you can take it as guideline for your logo-training. I hope this help you.

1) Create a new text layer

[image]

2) Take a pen tool and draw two lines so together they are looking like "a"

[image]

3) Turn text layer off, we don't need it anymore

[image]

4) Take "Ellipse Tool" and draw some ellipses. Now turn brushes window on. Select all the ellipses and drag it to the brushes window.

[image]

5) A new scatter brush created

[image]

6) Apply this brush to the "a" lines

[image]

7) Finnaly adjust the brush settings like this

[image]

Comment: My guess is that the above steps are exactly the steps involved in the original. One possible optimization that the creator of the original work may have done: a (step 8+) to render or commit the result so that the shapes where then editable. This way they can be adjusted/tweaked/removed manually...

Comment: Which could be done by going to `Object -> Expand Appearance`

Comment: I would simply start with taking the font (a)... then, outline the font... and follow the remainder of the steps as suggested..

Answer (score 11):

Maybe I'm old fashioned, but to add an answer that contrasts with the more scripted/automated suggestions, I'd suggest drawing a circle. Then duplicate it a bunch of times. And resize them. And then lay them out on the shape of a letter until it looks good to you.

Comment: one could incorporate a layer mask to help maintain the shape.

Comment: True, though that's still maybe overkill as the initial image doesn't show any cropped edges.

Comment: thanks for your ans but it takes a lot of time

Comment: Sometimes graphic design takes a lot of time. It's all in the details. ;)

Comment: Not only do I earn my living with "graphic design", most things I design (most non-designers would say "make" or "print") receive big "wow!" responses, especially when compared to what the non-designers make in Word with crappy clip-art. My designs take significantly longer than their Word-made stuff because I typically modify everything I use. I might require "twice as long" to design something, and that is significant to them. They make their stuff in ten minutes, my designs take "significantly" longer.

Answer (score 8):

Aside from placing the objects by hand, @mast0r has the normal solution to this problem.

### For those who aren't afraid of [Scriptographer](http://scriptographer.org/)...

And aren't running CS6. Here are further options for producing nice randomized effects.

**[Bubbel Bubbling](http://scriptographer.org/scripts/interactive-tools/bubbel-bubbling/)**
This is an interactive tool that places the bubbles as you draw with the Scriptographer tool.

[image]

**[Bubbel Bubbling stroke](http://scriptographer.org/scripts/general-scripts/bubbelbubbling/)**
A modification of the script to apply the effect to a selected path.

[image]

**[Randomdistribute](http://scriptographer.org/scripts/general-scripts/randomdistribute/)**
This tool just randomizes a selection of objects.

[image]

**[Variator](http://scriptographer.org/scripts/general-scripts/variator/)**
Randomize with control over hue, saturation, brightness, size and opacity.

[image]