# How do I fill a shape with many small icons in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm looking for something similar to this

[image: http://www.backupintelligence.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/data-security1.gif]

or this

[image: http://www.fiat-auto.co.jp/img/eco_header.png]

I basically have several smaller icons and I want to position them into a shape.

Is there a way photoshop can position them automatically or will I have to manually copy and resize them myself?

Comment: I don't think your going to be able to automate this, unless you have a really convincing pattern.

Comment: possible duplicate to [this](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13683/how-to-make-a-logo-where-a-letter-is-made-of-particles-of-varying-sizes) or [this](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17543/pointillism-mosaic-vector-bokeh?lq=1)

Answer (score 7):

## Semi-Manual

I think the best way to achieve this would be to **Define a Pattern** with your different icons, and layer them within your image/shape.

1. Open your icon
2. Select a marquee around it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + **Click** the thumbnail in the layer window)
3. **Edit > Define Pattern...**
4. Go back to your shape
5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> for a duplicate layer
6. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + **Click** on the new layer to marquee select
7. **Edit > Fill...**
8. Choose **Pattern** then select your *custom pattern*
9. *Manual:* Adjust placement of your icons on curves or remove unnecessary elements to taste

Rinse and repeat for each of the other icons, taking care to vary in size for depth and space.

[image: Define a Custom pattern for each icon]

> As you can see in the image above, there isn't a lot of padding around
>   my sample, so if you need your icon to have fewer repeats, you'll need
>   to make the tile larger for that icon. The more space, the lower the
>   quantity.

Answer (score 3):

There's an After Effects plug-in that will do this: http://aescripts.com/pastiche/

So, you could potentially set it up in AE and then export stills which could then be opened/further manipulated in Photoshop.

Comment: as far as I checked , this filter is for movie , can I use that for single frame/image ?

Answer (score 2):

Pattern will look repetetive. If you want unique look, you need to duplicate and place manually.