# recolor objects different versions from swatch (excel)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, illustrator-scripting, microsoft-excel

My question is similar to [Recolor Artwork: single swatch to multiple swatches](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/113526/recolor-artwork-single-swatch-to-multiple-swatches), however, instead of coloring random squares, I have objects such as a shirt that want to make multiple versions of, the colors should not be random, but are pre-defined. I have a list of these colors in rgb format.

I would ideally like to make it so the shading textures in the shirt change appropriately as well. What is the best way to go about this, make x number of copies of the shirt in one artboard and recolor all of them from a custom swatch? Or can I use a script that takes the single shirt artboard and recolors it from an excel matrix. Very new to illustrator and its scripting so please be thorough in your answers! Thank you!

[image]

Comment: You could do that. But this sounds like a X/Y problem to me. What are you trying to accomplish? If this is for example for a webpage just export one svg and let the webpage change the color

Comment: this is not for a webpage, its for an experiment. so I need x number of different copies of the shirt in different specified colors